# Apache VFS2 with Private Key but without a key file

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssh-keys, apache-vfs

I am wanting to use VFS2 to connect to an SFTP server using a private key.

However, the application will be running using Java EE on an application server; and so I don't want to store the private key in a file - I want to store it (encrypted) in a database instead; and then read the key and use it to connect.

However, all the instructions I can find (e.g. [How to use apache vfs2 for sftp with public-private-key and without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430315/how-to-use-apache-vfs2-for-sftp-with-public-private-key-and-without-password)) use a private key `file`, and apache VFS2 seems to require a file rather than a string in its identity provider object. (e.g. `IdentityInfo myIdentityInfo = new IdentityInfo(new File(openSSHPrivateKey));`)

I guess I could read the DB, save to a temporary file, then delete the temp file afterwards, but ideally I wouldn't use the local file system on the application server. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setIdentityInfo` you can (and should) use `SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setIdentityProvider`. This class allows you to use `IdentityInfo` if you want to use a file; but it also allows the option of using a `[BytesIdentityInfo][1]` object in its place, if your key is in a string (`.getBytes()`) rather than a File.